# how many transaction are in one process

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with meaning of `open_tran` column in `sys.sysprocesses`.
it return the number 2 for some processes but I wonder how one process can have two open transactions?

Could it be possible to say an example for me that a process can have two open transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nested transactions will increment that counter.**

The following script will demonstrate this:

```sql
select open_transaction_count
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@SPID;

begin tran;

select open_transaction_count
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@SPID;

begin tran;

select open_transaction_count
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@SPID;

rollback tran;
```

> Note that you should not use `sys.sysprocesses` as it has been deprecated. Use `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_connections` instead.